# Qt Gui and Threads

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt5

I would make a visual event manager that write everything in a listWidget in MainWindow, but doesn't work. And, if the ClassA launch a thread, how write a message in the listWidget? i've this classes:

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"
#include "classA.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    myClass= new classA();
}

QObject::connect(myClass, SIGNAL(makeSomething(QString)), this, SLOT(showMessageInConsole(QString)));

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    delete ui; 
}

void MainWindow::showMessageInConsole(QString msg) {
    ui->listWidget->addItem(msg);
}
```

**MainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "classA.h"

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void showMessageInConsole(QString msg);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    classA * myClass;
};

#endif
```

**ClassA.cpp**

```
ClassA::ClassA()
{
    // make something
    emit makeSomething("msg");
}

ServerThreaded::~ServerThreaded()
{
}
```

**ClassA.h**

```
#ifndef CLASSA_H
#define CLASSA_H

class ClassA: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ClassA(QWidget *parent);
    ~ClassA();


public slots:

signals:
    void makeSomething(QString msg);

private:

};

#endif
```

Comment: I've fixed code formatting and it turns out that you have connect outside a method. Another thing write exactly what are you trying to do! Title says something about threads, but included code doesn't have any usage of threads, only some mysterious destructor, which does nothing, for class which name suggest something about threads.

Answer (score 1):

You're emitting the `ClassA::makeSomething` signal before you have connected it anywhere. Move the signal emission somewhere else, for example a slot.

```
// classa.h

public slots:
    void emitMySignal();
```

```
// classa.cpp

void ClassA::emitMySignal()
{
    emit makeSomething("msg");
}
```

```
// mainwindow.h

signals:
    void requestMessage();
```

```
// mainwindow.cpp

QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(requestMessage()), myCLass, SLOT(emitMySignal()));
...
emit requestMessage();
```

*If the ClassA launch a thread, how write a message in the listWidget?*

By using signals and slots. Connect a signal from your worker object, to a signal of your `ClassA` class, and connect that signal from `ClassA` object to a slot in your `MainWindow`.